# FreeMember Update Profile only updating screen_name and email, not any other custom fields

Tags: custom-fields, freemember, users

I'm having a lingering FreeMember issue where regardless of what I include in the form it will only update the screen_name and the email address. It will not update the street_address, city, state, or zipcode

EE 2.7.2

Freemember 2.3.0

```
{exp:freemember:update_profile form_class="form" return="member"}

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">Email</label>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" value="{email}" />
 {error:email}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="screen_name">Screen Name</label><br />
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="screen_name" value="{screen_name}" />
 {error:screen_name}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="street_address">Address</label><br />
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="street_address" value="{street_address}" />
 {error:street_address}
</div>

<div class="row">
 <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
  <label for="city">City</label><br />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" value="{city}" />
  {error:city}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
  <label for="state">State</label><br />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" value="{state}" />
  {error:state}
 </div>
 <div class="form-group col-sm-2">
  <label for="zipcode">Zip Code</label><br />
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zipcode" value="{zipcode}" />
  {error:zipcode}
 </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
 <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Update Profile" class="btn" />
</div>

{/exp:freemember:update_profile}
```

Comment: Are you also using the Store module on this site?

Comment: No e-com in the system.

Comment: Are the form inputs correctly pre-filled with the existing member field values?

Comment: All of the custom fields are prefilling properly. Could it be related to what users can see on the back end?